# redesign database around selecting rows by time range

Tags: database-design, datetime

I currently have a MySQL database that grows about 50,000 rows a day. When querying data out of the database, I query information from the `info` table and use a subquery on the `session` table to refine by date range like:

```
SELECT info.sessionID, info.otherstuff, t.time FROM info
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT session.sessionID, session.time FROM session
WHERE session.time > :afterSomeDate AND session.time < :beforeSomeOtherDate) as t 
ORDER BY t.time DESC
```

This causes an exponentially large bottleneck in query time as the date range increases. As I am completely redesigning the database, any suggestions are valid including different DB types. There is currently a 3 month `RANGE` partition on the `time` column, as well as an `INDEX`.

During my research I have done a few tests directly in the MySQL database. For instance a query to select every session in my table in a date range of 2 months, has a duration time of .453s and fetch time of 81s (returned 1.7 million rows). According to the accepted answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425134/mysql-duration-and-fetch-time), my bottleneck could really be the network connection between database and the application.

What else could I do to get a significant performance increase?

Comment: Your query is missing an `ON` clause. Can you edit the question and fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Look into PostgresQL with Timescale Extension:

https://docs.timescale.com/v1.1/using-timescaledb